# HTML 5 Canvas to Video Stream not working

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, html5-video

I'm currently trying to use the `captureStream()` method to convert a canvas to a live video stream. Therefore, I first created a canvas, that you can draw in (therefore I'm using [this little code](http://www.williammalone.com/articles/create-html5-canvas-javascript-drawing-app/). So I have a canvas and I can draw in that canvas. Now, I want a video stream beneath that, which permanently shows exactly the content of this canvas.

So my code is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>HTML5 Create HTML5 Canvas JavaScript Drawing App Example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.js"></script>
    <!--[if IE]><script type="text/javascript" src="excanvas.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="html5-canvas-drawing-app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="canvasDiv"></div>
    <video id="video" autoplay></video>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
         prepareCanvas();
        var canvas = $('#canvasDiv');
        var video = $('#video');

        var stream = canvas.captureStream();
        video.srcObject = stream;
});
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

- the JS files you find under the link (but those are only interesting for the drawing, so they won't change anything here).

When I run this code, I immediately get the message `canvas.captureStream()` is not a function. Does anybody see a mistake or can tell me why its not working at all?

Thanks

Comment: You are calling it on a jquery object, not on the HTMLElement. cshould be canvas[0]. Also IIRC the canvas should be initialised (with something drawn on its context) before calling captureStream.

Answer (score 1):

Ajay's answer correctly points the first issue : You are calling the `captureStream` method of a jQuery object, which doesn't have such a method.

The second issue is that `#canvasDiv` is a `<div>` element, and not a `<canvas>`. Only `<canvas> and MediaElements (``&``) have a` captureStream()` method.

So you need to have a `<canvas>` element in your document, and to get the Element referenced by the jQuery object, e.g

```
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

```js
const $canvas = $('#myCanvas'); // the jQuery object
const canvasElement = $canvas[0]; // the real element
```

Now, note that to be able to capture a stream from an `<canvas>` element, its context must be initialized, or `captureStream()` will throw.

```js
const canvas = $('#myCanvas')[0]; // [0] => the element
// first initialize a context
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'); // or whatever ('webgl', 'webgl2' ...)
// then you can get the stream
const stream = canvas.captureStream(30);
// const $video = $('#video');
// $video[0].srcObject = stream;
// $video[0].play();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

Also beware that as soon as you taint your `<canvas>` (e.g by drawing cross-origin media on it), the stream will be muted.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. But still, it doesn't seem to work... Using the code you provided I now the error `canvas.getContext is not a function`...

Comment: @nameless you are still using your `var canvas = $('#canvasDiv');` ? It should be `var canvas = $('#canvasDiv')[0];` Oh my bad !!! there is no canvas element in your code !

Comment: it is, I'm trying this code now: var canvas = $('#canvasDiv')[0];
      var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        var video = $('#video');

        var stream = canvas.captureStream();
        video.srcObject = stream;

Comment: Well, the canvas gets initialized by the script (called with the function `prepareCanvas()`, so the canvas is there then

Comment: You can find the output of the log for `console.log('canvas element', canvas );` in the comment of the answer of Ajay

Comment: @nameless but `$('#canvasDiv')` points to an `<div>`, not an `<canvas>`. So the correct jquery selector should be `$('#canvas')`

Comment: okay, I see.. now, I don't en error, but also no video.. so i can draw on the canvas, but don't see it in the video..

Comment: `video.play()` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144520/discussion-between-nameless-and-kaiido).

Answer (score 0):

It seems issue is at `var canvas = $('#canvasDiv');` print the canvas object in console and see. `canavs` should be the canvas element, not the enclosed div element.

```
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
var video = document.querySelector('video');
var stream = canvas.captureStream();

video.srcObject = stream;
```

Try the demo https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/capture/canvas-record/

**Update:** As per the git url: https://github.com/williammalone/Simple-HTML5-Drawing-App/blob/master/html5-canvas-drawing-app.js#L405

You can get canvas & stream as follows:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var stream = canvas.captureStream();
console.log('canvas element', canvas, stream);
```

Comment: Might be right, I chaned it to `var canvas = $('canvas');` now, but its still the same error appearing...

Comment: Which Browser version you are using? I didn't see `<canvas>` element in your code,  what does `prepareCanvas()` function will do? Better provide a JSfiddle sample

Comment: I'm using Chrome Version 58. You can't find the hole code for prepareCanvas() and the other on the page I mentioned in my post: http://www.williammalone.com/articles/create-html5-canvas-javascript-drawing-app/

Comment: print canvas object as `console.log('canvas element', canvas );` and provide me the log

Comment: <canvas width="490" height="220" id="canvas"></canvas>